# i have nokia windows phone keeps saying stack overflow lines35 and 10 what does that mean

Tags: 8.0

I have a Nokia Windows Phone. In the web browser, it says:

```
Stack Overflow - Lines 10, and 35
```

How do I get to the website?

Comment: Does this do this for all website addresses? Does search work? Can you include a screenshot?